# Unable to access UserControl using X:Name from XAML Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is my user control  embedded into my page list view

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ZTask">
        <local:AddUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have Named it as MyUserControl using X: Name. I tried accessing this in my page cs file but it gives me an error saying "The name 'MyUserControl' does not exist in the current context".
Help me fix this issue.

Comment: In ListView,even if you set x:name, it is invalid.Because there are multiple userControls in the ListView, it does not know which one you point to.Why do you want to get usercontrol?And you could try to use **Binding** to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: are you able to see your `AddUserControl`in toolbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which particular instance of `AddUserControl` are you expecting to get a reference to since there will be an `AddUserControl` added per item in the `ListView`?

If you want to do something with the `AddUserControl`**s**, you could handle the `Loaded` event for each one of them:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ZTask">
        <local:AddUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Loaded="OnLoaded"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddUserControl auc = (AddUserControl)sender;
    //...
}
```